# EXT-JS: datastore get all rows

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have an datastore assigned to an table through an PagingToolbar. The paging size is limited to 10 per page. Now I want to create an export-function which exports all entries of this datastore.

I have done the following code:

```
var countRows  = dataSource.getCount();
var csvData    = new Array();
for ( var row = 0; row < countRows; row++ ) {
  csvData.push( dataSource.getAt( row ).data[ 'messageID' ] ) );
}
```

this works fine, but only for the visible rows. If I change the first line to

```
var countRows  = dataSource.getTotalCount();
```

I get the right count of total rows, but when I want to access a row, that is not currently shown, I get an exception.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only rows that are currently being shown in your grid are actually loadd into the store. That's how paging work. If you'd like to get all rows, you need to load them from the server first.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I know that. But I don't know how to say the Store how to load all data. I tried the following. 'dataSource.load( { params: start: 0, limit: totalCount } } ); But this don't work for me

Comment: I'm not sure if loading this into the store that's bound o the grid is the wisest way to do it, be cause it will result in grid trying to display all your records (which is not the best idea, if you have thousands of them). Perhaps you should create a separate store, not bound to grid or pagingbar, and load data into it.